# GetValue and SetValue returning only 2nd character of the variable and not the full value of the variable

Tags: variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets, while-loop, google-api

In my SMAfind script I have the following code

```
stock = startCell.offset(rowNumber,0).getValue();
startCell.offset(rowNumber, 1).setValue(stock[1]);**
```

As I debug the varaible 'stock' correctly identifies the stock as BCE.TO
But only 'C' [the second letter of the variable Stock] gets entered into my worksheet.

The same occurs for all 49 entries for the variable 'Stock'

How do I modify this function or what else do I need to do the ensure I get the full BCE.TO reported in my worksheet?

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated... Thanks

Andre

The relevant code is:
var rowNumber

```
rowNumber = 1; 

while (!startCell.offset(rowNumber,0).isBlank())
    {
        // Pull the data for the selected stock from Yahoo Finance Canada
        url = `https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/${stock}?p=${stock}`;
        source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
        contentText = source.getContentText();

        stock = startCell.offset(rowNumber,0).getValue();
        startCell.offset(rowNumber, 1).setValue(stock[1]);
        startCell.offset(1, 2).setValue(stock[1]);

        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1;

    }
```

Comment: `getValue()` returns a value not an array.  If its a string then `stock[1]` will be the second character of the string.  You need to use `setValue(stock)`